# How can i get Created date of a column in SQL server Table?

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2005

I use the following query to get information about columns of a SQL Table :

```
SELECT * from information_schema.columns 
WHERE table_name = 'userpersonalinformation'
```

but I can't find any data about creation date for each column ... Is there any way to get creation date of a column in a table ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think that information is available in any system tables or the information schema views. I would look for that information in a source control system rather than the database.

Comment: Unfortunately it's not under source control

Comment: Then I would fix that. sys.tables will tell you the last mod date of the table structure, but not the specific column.

Comment: You'd have to use sys.objects, not sys.tables

Comment: @gbn it just get me modified date for table ( many operations can cause this to be changed )

Comment: sys.columns / sys.all_columns has an object_id but it's the table object_id, I don't see an object_id for the column / entry in sys.columns for the column